# Binary operator '&=' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make multiple checks accumulating the result in a `Bool`:

My code is:

```
 var validParams = login.characters.count > 4;
 validParams &= password.characters.count > 6;
 validParams &= ...
 // more validations
 if (validParams) {...}
```

But I get the error `Binary operator '&=' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands`.

How can I do this work or rewrite this code in a non-verbose mode?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik **No** This is most definitely not a duplicate of the linked question. The answer to *this* question is that `&=` is a bitwise operation and can't be applied to `Bool`.

Comment: @JeremyP - oh sorry my bro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&=` is a [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and can only be applied to integer types. `&&=` which is what you need doesn't actually exist because of [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You need to write

```
validParams = validParams && ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't actually exist because of short circuiting*"? You can implement a `&&=` operator which short-circuits, compare [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156429/2976878).

Comment: @Hamish Yes you can implement it, but I assume it is not implemented  because short circuiting makes the side effects confusing. There's no `&&=` in C either.

Comment: I don't really see how the side effects of `b &&= x()` would be any more confusing than with `b = b && x()`, but each to their own I guess.

Comment: @Hamish The second way is probably considered to make the short circuiting a bit more obvious I guess.

Answer (score 5):

As [@JeremyP says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154441/2976878), `&=` is the [in-place bitwise AND operator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541307), which only operates on integer types. However, there's nothing to stop you from defining your own `&&=` operator for an in-place logical AND operation:

```
infix operator &&= : AssignmentPrecedence

func &&=(lhs: inout Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) {
    // although it looks like we're always evaluating rhs here, the expression "rhs()" is
    // actually getting wrapped in a closure, as the rhs of && is @autoclosure.
    lhs = lhs && rhs()
}
```

You can then simply use it like so:

```
func someExpensiveFunc() -> Bool {
    // ...
    print("some expensive func called")
    return false
}

var b = false

b &&= someExpensiveFunc() // someExpensiveFunc() not called, as (false && x) == false.
print(b) // false

b = true

b &&= someExpensiveFunc() // someExpensiveFunc() called, as (true && x) == x
print(b) // false
```

As you can see, because we made the `rhs:` parameter of `&&=` an `@autoclosure` parameter, we can have short-circuit evalutation for when the `lhs` is `false`.